# Reference for one-loop photon propagator in the frame of the electroweak theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, propagator

Does anyone know any reference where the photon propagator is dimentionaly regularized to one-loop in the frame of electroweak theory (with vacuum polarization involving Faddeev-Popov ghosts and Goldstone bosons)?